# code sends one big array to hireAssistant but I want to send individual permutations one by one

Tags: java

```
public static int [] makeArray(int n){
    int arr[] = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = i + 1;
    }
    return arr;
}

public static int hireAssistant1(int[] arr, int n) {
    ArrayList<Integer> hired = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int best = arr[0];
    hired.add(best);
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < best) {
            best = arr[i];
            hired.add(best);
        }
    }

    return hired.size();
}
public static void methodThreePerm(List<Integer> list, int n) {
    int size = factorial(n);
    int [] arr = new int [list.size()];
    arr = toIntArray(list);

    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int hires = hireAssistant1(arr, n);
        if (hires == 2)
            sum = sum + 1;
    }

    System.out.println("Method 3: s/n! = " + sum /size);
}

public static int factorial(int n) {
    if (n == 1) return 1;
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    if (n == 2) return 2;
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
}

static int[] toIntArray(List<Integer> list) {
    int[] ret = new int[list.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
        ret[i] = list.get(i);
    return ret;
}

static List<Integer> listToList(List<List<Integer>> list) {
    List<Integer> flat =
            list.stream()
                    .flatMap(List::stream)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return flat;
}

public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] arr) {
    List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    permuteHelper(list, new ArrayList<>(), arr);
    return list;
}

private void permuteHelper(List<List<Integer>> list, List<Integer> resultList, int[] arr) {
    if (resultList.size() == arr.length) {
        list.add(new ArrayList<>(resultList));
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (resultList.contains(arr[i])) {
                continue;
            }
            resultList.add(arr[i]);
            permuteHelper(list, resultList, arr);
            resultList.remove(resultList.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Assignment8 pa = new Assignment8();
    int n = 6;
    List<List<Integer>> p = pa.permute(makeArray(n));
    List<Integer> list = listToList(p);
    System.out.println("N = 6");
    methodThreePerm(list, n);
```

The expectation is to enumerate all the n! permutations of the arrays of ranks,
check  - the number of arrays where we hire exactly
twice, and output the probability: /!.
I have added the base methods needed to check any array, but cant seem to figure out how to send an array of permutations to my hire Assistant method to check for each hire

Comment: you seem to be reinventing the wheel here, what's the purpose of the toIntArray method when you can just do list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray() ?

Comment: Can you improve your question so that anyone can help you? I can't seem to wrap my head around what a list of all the permutations of a list of 6 numbers has to do with hiring assistants and what exactly you're trying to check. You can also replace the body of makeArray with this one liner return IntStream.iterate(1, i -> ++i).limit(n).toArray(); or just stick with lists or primitive arrays and not use both types throughout.

Comment: the hireAssistant method will check who is hired in the array based on their rank, 1 being the lowest.

Comment: so if the array is [3,2,1] it will hire all 3 people because 3 is the first option until something better comes along

Comment: can you pinpoint the exact problem in your code? eg "this variable prints 0 but I expected something else"

Comment: the problem im having is sending the permutation of the arrays to my hireAssisant method.

Comment: your code compiles and runs and you're sending this array to your hireAssistant method:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 6, 1, 2, 5, 4, 6, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, +4,220 more]

What were you expecting to send?

Comment: thats the problem. its only one big array. Im trying to send each permutation

Comment: then it looks like you want to avoid using listToList

Comment: but how can i send that list of lists to hireAssistant since it takes an array as a parameter?

Comment: Added answer to show you the code, essentially hireAssistant will remain largely unchanged, just accepting list instead of primitive array, and methodThreePerm will send every individual permutation to hireAssistant.

Comment: I suggest editing your question to say, "code sends one big array to hireAssistant but I want to send individual permutations one by one"

Answer (score 0):

Stick with using lists instead of converting to arrays to simplify your logic and send the list of lists to methodThreePerm so that you can send the individual permutations to hireAssistant.

```
   public static int [] makeArray(int n){
        return IntStream.iterate(1, i -> ++i).limit(n).toArray();
    }

    public static int hireAssistant1(List<Integer> arr, int n) {
        ArrayList<Integer> hired = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int best = arr.get(0);
        hired.add(best);
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            if (arr.get(i) < best) {
                best = arr.get(i);
                hired.add(best);
            }
        }

        return hired.size();
    }

    public static void methodThreePerm(List<List<Integer>> list, int n) {
        int size = factorial(n);

        double sum = 0;
        for (List<Integer> arr : list) {
            int hires = hireAssistant1(arr, n);
            if (hires == 2)
                ++sum;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum:" + sum);
        System.out.println("Size:" + size);
        System.out.println("Method 3: s/n! = " + sum /size);
    }

    public static int factorial(int n) {
        if (n == 1) return 1;
        if (n == 0) return 1;
        if (n == 2) return 2;
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }

    public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] arr) {
        List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        permuteHelper(list, new ArrayList<>(), arr);
        return list;
    }

    private void permuteHelper(List<List<Integer>> list, List<Integer> resultList, int[] arr) {
        if (resultList.size() == arr.length) {
            list.add(new ArrayList<>(resultList));
        } else {
            for (int i : arr) {
                if (resultList.contains(i)) {
                    continue;
                }
                resultList.add(i);
                permuteHelper(list, resultList, arr);
                resultList.remove(resultList.size() - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Assignment8 pa = new Assignment8();
        int n = 6;
        List<List<Integer>> p = pa.permute(makeArray(n));
        System.out.println("N = 6");
        methodThreePerm(p, n);
    }
```

Prints:

```
N = 6
Sum:197280.0
Size:720
Method 3: s/n! = 274.0
```

Comment: yes that looks good but the output of s/n! should be 0.38055555555555554

Comment: Sum should be 273.9999999999999888 ?

Comment: From this point onwards you should debug your program on your own, see [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips

Comment: I figured it out. There was no need for the inner for loop you made for method 3. Thank you for all your help, I was going to explode. Now my method 1 is equivalent to method 3

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, I didnt remove your original loop after adding the replacement which was the error

Answer (score 0):

```
static void methodOneSum1(int n) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (double i = 2; i <= n; i++)
            sum += 1 / ((double) (i - 1));
        System.out.println("Method 1: n = " + (sum / n));
    }
```

this output for this is when n = 6

```
Method 1: n = 0.38055555555555554
```

which is supposed to equal the methodThreePerm